# How i get value from all dynamic textbox by using Class in php

Tags: php, javascript

i have this dynamic textbox, and i want to get value by using class. by php

```
<input id="op1" name="po1" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op2" name="po2" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op3" name="po3" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op4" name="po4" class="max" size="50">
<input id="op5" name="po5" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op6" name="po6" class="lol" size="50">
<input id="op6" name="po6" class="lol" size="50">
```

in this textbox there are "key", "max" and "lol" class 
How i get value from this all dynamic textbox by using  only Class "Key" in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what you mean about "using class", however you can loop the $_POST array to get access to the variables like so:

```
// Show the variables
var_dump($_POST);
// Loop the variables
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
    echo "{$k} = {$v}";
}
```

Alternatively you can group your vars together in your HTML like so:

```
<input id="op1" name="po[1]" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op2" name="po[2]" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op3" name="po[3]" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op4" name="po[4]" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op5" name="po[5]" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op6" name="po[6]" class="key" size="50">
```

Which then means that PHP sees the POST variable **po** as an array, like so:

```
// Show the variables
var_dump($_POST);
// Loop the po variables
foreach($_POST['po'] as $k => $v){
    echo "{$k} = {$v}";
}
```

Comment: Thank You Sir..... it solved by you suggest... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't because the value of the `class` attribute is not transferred to php. Only the values of the `name` attribute and the `value` attribute will be transferred.

Comment: but the name may be dynanic like op1,op6, op8.. and class only same..

Comment: The `name`s will be transfered, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/gbxuxH . As they all start with the same characters, you could make use of that pattern by looking for it `$_POST` (if you have a post form).

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="op1" name="po1" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op2" name="po2" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op3" name="po3" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op4" name="po4" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op5" name="po5" class="key" size="50">
<input id="op6" name="po6" class="key" size="50">

<input type="button" id="get" value="get">


$("#get").click(function() {

    var myarray1 = new Array();
    $(".key").each(function(i) {
        alert($(this).val());
        myarray1[i] = $(this).val(); 
    });


});
```

I got you question, you can get this way

http://jsfiddle.net/6jf2r/2/

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you need some javascript to do it. Not tested, but here how it goes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = [];
  // Get value of each input element that has key class
  $('input.key').each(function() {
    // Push it to an array
    values.push($(this).value());
  });

  // Send to php
  $.ajax({
    url : 'mypage.php?q=' + values.join(':'),
    success: function() {
       // Do something if you wish
    }
  });
});
```